# What's the name of this method to find a value in a very efficient way

Tags: arrays, sorting, find

If you have a table/array with a lot of **sorted** int values, and you want to find one, instead of going one by one, I know there is a very efficient method that does this: Firstly, it goes to the middle element. If the element value is greater than the searched value, then it ignores all the elements above this one, and goes down to the middle. Else it goes up to the middle. And continues doing this until the value has been found.

In pseudo it would be something like this

```
searched_value = X
actual_index = length(array)/2
offset = actual_index

while(true){

    if array[actual_index] = searched_value then return actual_index

    if array[actual_index] > searched_value then
        offset = round_down( offset / 2 )
        actual_index = actual_index - offset
    else
        offset = round_up( offset / 2 )
        actual_index = actual_index + offset

}
```

I know there is a name for this method but I can't remember it.

Comment: It's called [Binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you're thinking of a binary search.

I don't know what language you're working in, but there might be an API call for this.